# user www-data cannot remove file

Tags: php, bash, exec, rm

In php I do the following:

```
exec('remove_file.sh', $output, $return);
```

where remove_file.sh is the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
rm -f /tmp/test.pdf
```

I verified that this script is run by www-data and test.pdf is owned by myuser but with 666 (rw-rw-rw-) permissions. /tmp is owned by root and has 666 permission.

The script returns 1 (general error) without any output.

If I try from a terminal:

```
sudo su www-data -c 'rm -f /tmp/test.pdf'
```

I get:

```
cannot remove `/tmp/test.pdf': Operation not permitted
```

How can I remove this file from a php script?

Comment: Whats the output of `ls -al /tmp/test.pdf` ?

Comment: have you tried setting the execute bit? chmod 777 to give rwxrwxrwx? what are the permissions of the directory? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened

Comment: $fyr that is: -rw-rw-rw- 1 myuser myuser

Comment: @Waygood I just did but without result

Comment: try using unlink() in php instead of rm -rf in shell

Comment: @Dave unlink gives: 'Operation not permitted'

Comment: @Dave setting the execute bit on the /tmp directory (777) did the trick!

Comment: could try 755 or 722 instead then rule of thumb 777 is bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to make sure `www-user` has write permission to the directory, as well as the file. This depends on the filesystem, but most require this for `rm` or `mv` operations.

So `chmod 777 /tmp` should do the trick.

**Edit:** The above may not be a secure way to accomplish the desired availability. Depending on your setup, a more thorough way to accomplish this would be to add `www-user` to the `users` group (assuming `myuser` primary group is `users`), then set the `/tmp` directory to rwx for user & group.

```
# usermod -g users www-user
# chmod 770 /tmp
```

Allowing everyone to read, write and execute in `/tmp` is not suitable for multi-user or unsecured boxes, and whilst it may work fine on a well secured server, you are giving a lot of access to anyone who compromises the box.

An even better alternative is to have php upload files to a more local directory instead of using bash scripts using [$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) and then use PHP again to delete them with [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php). This way all files will belong to `www-user`. Remember that it's essential to validate files thoroughly before allowing uploads to prevent attacks via [c99 and similar malware](http://www.madirish.net/?article=271).

EDIT (from OP):

Though the security issues do not apply in *my* case, I completely agree with the previous edit. Using /tmp was the lazy way out. But the real problem was that I tested creating a file under my own user and then continued testing from www-data. Under the default permissions of /tmp you cannot (rightly so) delete another users file nor overwrite it. This resulted in various issues, not only with rm.

Comment: chmod 666 actually broke some session functionality on my system (which I do not understand because I think the permissions were 666 already) but 777 resolved all issues including rm. If you wish, edit your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @zensys - It probably needs to be 722 (execute for owner -- write-only for others), but have edited to 777 as that works for you.

Comment: Even better `chmod 1777 /tmp`, so that only owner of the file can delete or rename it. The `1` is the [sticky bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

Comment: @fedorqi but the user was explicitely asking to remove a file as user 'foo' created by user 'bar'...

Comment: @Oshawott, @zensys: a `chmod 777 /tmp` will allow **anybody** to remove and recreate any file within `/tmp`, which is a severe security whole. countless hours have been spent to make tempfile mechanisms create files/directories within /tmp without allowing other people to read those files, and now you come and simply tell people that they should allow everyone everything. at least you should confine your permissions to a subfolder, e.g. `/tmp/myapplication/` where other processes are likely to not put sensitive data into.

Comment: @umlaeute - Your comment cut off. It entirely depends on the operating environment. There are better ways to do it like adding 'www-user' to the users group then setting `chmod 770 /tmp`. This is not innately insecure assuming it's a single user box.

Comment: @Oshawott, yes it depends on the system; but this is like telling people to give away their password because depending on their systems they might have a fingerprint reader installed....and the OP asked for access for the the PHP-process running as "www-data", which indicates that they want to do that from a webserver, which is inherently NOT a single-user box.

Comment: @umlaeute I don't think you understand file permissions. You would have to have a valid login to the box to perform operations even in a `chmod 777` directory. Anyway, I have updated the answer with some security recommendations.

Comment: @umlaeute - Also, to be clear about one thing: it's far less dangerous to allow anyone to upload to `/tmp` than to `/var/www/public/uploads`. At `/tmp` they still have no way to access what they've uploaded or to cron it.